# Data not updating in DB Sqflite Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The task text in `edit_todo_screen` is not updated. I'm using the same code as in `item_tasks`, where I change the status of the task to move between "Done" and "Archived" - everything works well here. I tried to change only the status in `edit_todo_screen`, but it does not change, although the code is identical to the code in `item_tasks`. Perhaps the problem is that I'm not passing the parameters correctly to `edit_todo_screen`. I need to be able to change the status of the task and the text of the task itself in `edit_todo_screen`. Attached below is a screenshot of the error that occurs when clicking the button in `edit_todo_screen`
Tell me, please, what could be my mistake?

**cubit_db**

```
 class AppCubit extends Cubit<AppStates> {
      AppCubit() : super(AppInitialState());
    
      static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);
    
    void updateDatabase(String status, int id) async {
        database!.rawUpdate(
            'UPDATE tasks SET status = ? WHERE id = ?', [status, id]).then((value) {
          getDataBase(database);
          emit(AppUpdateDatabaseState());
        });
      }

void createDatabase() {
    openDatabase(
      'todo.db',
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (database, version) {
        database
            .execute(
                'CREATE TABLE tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, status TEXT)')
            .then((value) => print('Table Created'))
            .catchError((error) {
          print('Error When Creating Table ${error.toString()}');
        });
      },
      onOpen: (database) {
        getDataBase(database);
        print('database opened');
      },
    ).then((value) {
      database = value;
      emit(AppCreateDatabaseState());
    });
  }

inserToDatabase({required String title}) async {
    await database!.transaction((txn) async {
      txn
          .rawInsert(
              'INSERT INTO tasks (title, status) VALUES ("$title","New")')
          .then((value) {
        getDataBase(database);
        print('$value Inserted Successfully');
        emit(AppInsertDatabaseState());
      }).catchError((error) {
        print('Error When inserting Table ${error.toString()}');
      });
    });
  }
```

**new_tasks_list**

```
class NewTasksScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        var tasks = AppCubit.get(context).newTasks;
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: tasks.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => TaskItem(tasks: tasks[index]),
            ),
          ]),
        );
      },
    );
```

**tasks_item**

```
class TaskItem extends StatelessWidget {
  Map? tasks;

  TaskItem({this.tasks});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      key: Key(tasks!['title']),
      shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 8),
      color: Colors.black,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 0.5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      borderOnForeground: false,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Text(
            // '${state.loadedUser[index].description}',
            tasks!['title'],
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 21.0,
              // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          // Text(
          //   tasks!['status'],
          //   style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
          // ),
        ]),
        trailing: IconButton(
          tooltip: 'Archive Todo',
          highlightColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            AppCubit.get(context).updateDatabase('Archive', tasks!['id']);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.archive,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          tooltip: 'Done Todo',
          highlightColor: Colors.green,
          onPressed: () {
            AppCubit.get(context).updateDatabase('Done', tasks!['id']);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => EditTodoScreen(
                title: tasks!['title'],
                id: tasks!['id'],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**edit_todo_screen**

```
class EditTodoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Map? tasks;
  String title;
  int id;
  EditTodoScreen({Key? key, required this.title, required this.id})
      : super(key: key);

  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.text = title;

    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text(
                'Edit Todo',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            body: _body(context),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _body(context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            autocorrect: true,
            maxLines: 2,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter todo message'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          // ElevatedButton(
          //   // style:,
          //   onPressed: () {
          //     AppCubit.get(context).updateDatabase('Done', id);
          //   },
          //   child: Text(
          //     'Update Data',
          //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber.shade700),
          //   ),
          // ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              AppCubit.get(context).updateDatabase('Done', id);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: _updateBtn(context),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _updateBtn(context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Update Todo',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17.0,
              color: Colors.amber.shade700,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with the fact that database is not set in the second case. The code fails because you try to access a null value that then is checked with the "!" operator.  Look where you set the database and check if that code is called in both code flows.

**edit:**
I think this line in edit todo screen is your problem: `AppCubit.get(context).updateDatabase('Done', id);`. If I am not mistaken AppCubit.get(context) returns null. The easiest way to check if I am right would be to replace it with the following:

```
final appCubit = AppCubit.get(context);
print('$appCubit');
appCubit.updateDatabase('Done', id);
```

If I am right, you should see "null" in your terminal.

What I think happens is, that the app cubit is not provided in the context anymore, because you pushed the todo screen as a new screen on the navigator. With that, the context that is provided is that of the navigator (or probably the material app in your case) which is above the point where you provide the AppCubit.

I am kind of guessing though, because I only see half of your code. I hope it helps nevertheless. :)

Comment: I didn’t understand a bit) I added a method to the question where I create and write to the DB. Can you please see)